# Android Studio Rendering Problems - Missing styles?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I get following error in the `Preview` window of `Android Studio`:

> Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for
>   this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a
>   different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Failed to find
>   '?attr/actionBarPopupTheme' in current theme. (4 similar errors not
>   shown)

I have created a custom style/theme. This is the regarding `styles.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle"   tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background"  tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/white</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="background">@color/bg_common</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/title</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/title</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/title</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My layout file header looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:background="@color/bg_common_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

...
```

And in my manifest file I have added in the application tag:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

Why do I get the error? I also choosed `CustomActionBarTheme` in my Preview windows as Theme. Am I missing something? Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Try changing the SDK preview version to an older version

Comment: Thanks! Setting the API Level from 23 to 22 helped. You can add this as an answer to my question and I will set it as confirmed answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android Studio uses the latest SDK installed to preview layout files. This can lead to preview errors due to missing styles - switching to an older API level (e.g. from 23 to 22) can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to change layout theme (near SDK preview version button)
Works fine